# I add a cookie, i see it added, then its no longer there

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

So I have been working on this for quite a while and cant seem to find an answer that helps. I am creating a cookie that holds a refresh token string. After I add it i can see it in my Request.Cookies as being added but it doesnt show up in the developer console and my program can't seem to find it.

Here is my creation and adding which is ran when they are successfully authenticated:

```
Response.Cookies.Remove("RefreshToken");
FormsAuthenticationTicket tick = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, 
    response.AppUser.Username, 
    DateTime.Now, 
    DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(response.AppUser.ExpiresIn), 
    true, 
    response.AppUser.AccessToken);

string encrypt = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(tick);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("RefreshToken", encrypt);
cookie.Value = response.AppUser.RefreshToken;
cookie["RemembeMe"] = rememberMe.ToString();
cookie.Secure = true;
cookie.Name = "RefreshToken";
cookie.Path = Request.ApplicationPath;
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here is me retrieving it in the Global.asax when my authentication Token is expired at the beginning of a request:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"] != null)
{
  var z = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["RefreshToken"].Value;
  Resources.ReauthorizeUser rau = new Resources.ReauthorizeUser();       
}
```

Here is some of my Web.Config:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" regenerateExpiredSessionId="false"/>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="5" protection="All" cookieless="UseCookies" slidingExpiration="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Let me know if i am missing any important code. Any help would be amazing, this has been driving me nuts.

Comment: At what point in the request pipeline does that code run that adds the cookie? Is there any other code that also sets that cookie or overwrites it? What do you see in the browser's development console, is the cookie listed there? At what point in the request pipeline are you retrieving the cookie?

Comment: Ah i knew i would leave out some important info. Good questions, i will update above. oh and i did answer about the development console, it never shows up there.

Comment: Looks like you're setting the cookie value to the string encrypt (in the HttpCookie constructor), but then overwrite the value to response.AppUser.RefreshToken.

Comment: Yeah, good point. Would that keep it from being created tho?

Comment: So after that cookie is created you don't see it at all in the browser in response headers?

Comment: Correct, it never shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookie will only be sent if the request is made over SSL.
Try `cookie.Secure = false;` in case you're not using SSL.

Comment: Hmm so yeah I'm guessing on localhost it wouldn't be SSL?

Comment: Unless you specifically set that up, I don't believe so.

Comment: Yep that was it. I knew it had to be something simple like that. Thank you!